# Bootstrap contact form not function -php

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form

I had coded html and php but cloudsblack84@gmail.com(mail address) still cannot receive mail form my website ( http://cloudsblack.info/ ) and at the end when I clicked the submit button will go into blank page (http://cloudsblack.info/index.php) . Sorry I am just beginner on web design need to learn a lot from you guys .

HTML PART

```
    <!-- Contact Section -->
<section id="contact" class="contacts-section">
    <div class="container content-lg">
        <div class="title-v1">
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
            <p>I'm always happy to hear from you. Please contact or email me for appointment or service enquiry.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row contacts-in">
            <div class="col-md-6 md-margin-bottom-40">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Kuala Lumpur</li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (6)016-7187764</li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <a href="-removed-email-">-removed-email-</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                 <form method="post" action="index.php">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                        </div>                
                    </div>

                    <label>Email<span class="color-red">*</span></label>
                    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control">
                        </div>                
                    </div>

                    <label>City</label>
                    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                            <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control">
                        </div>                
                    </div>

                    <label>Telephone</label>
                    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                            <input type="text" name="telephone" class="form-control">
                        </div>                
                    </div>


                    <label>Interested</label>
                    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                            <input type="text" name="interested" class="form-control">
                        </div>                
                    </div>

                    <label>Message</label>
                    <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                        <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-0">
                            <textarea rows="8" name="message" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>                
                    </div>

                    <p><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-u btn-brd btn-brd-hover btn-u-dark">Send Message</button></p>
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>
```

PHP PART

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$interested = $_POST['interested'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];

if($submit){

$from = 'From: -removed-domain-'."\r\n"; 
$to = '-removed-email-'; 
$subject = "Message from -removed-domain-";
$body = "".
    "From: ".$name."\n".
    "E-mail: ".$email."\n".
    "City: ".$city."\n".
    "Telephone: ".$telephone."\n".
    "Interested: ".$interested."\n".
    "Message: ".$message."\n";

if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)){
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
}
else{
    die('<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'); 
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Cant help you without the php part.

Comment: sorry .. i just added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the message `Something went wrong, go back and try again!` your mail server is incorrectly configured within `php.ini` or it has timed-out

If you see `Your message has been sent!`, check your spam folder.

If all else fails, access your mail server logs through WHM or CPanel or contact your hosting provider

---

$submit = $_POST['submit'];

You havn't given the `<button name='submit'>` a value, `if($submit){` is false/non-existent in your POST data.

---

Still not a reason for the blank page, need to look at your apache/php error logs or ask your hosting provider.

Comment: Hi Zanderwar , after I clicked sent ..its just go blank page http://cloudsblack.info/index.php  ... that is no "Something went wrong, go back and try again!" or "Your message has been sent!" ... thanks or your reply

Comment: Change things back and see my original post, your script never gets to the `mail()` function, and still NOT the reason for a blank page. See error logs.

Comment: Yes ..I already put it in HTML <p><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-u btn-brd btn-brd-hover btn-u-dark">Send Message</button></p> and changed the code back .

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - We are not getting any further without an error, read the error_reporting documentation or consult your hosting provider.